# Can't get value from radio button that has an image replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have been using this code to pull the selected radio button name and display it elsewhere. It has been working fine, however there is a set of radio buttons which have been replaced by images that are selected instead. This code does not work for them, I'm not sure what needs to be changed?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.element_1 input').on('change', function() { 
            var x = ($('input[name=tmcp_radio_1]:checked', '.element_1').val().split('_')[0]); 
            document.getElementById("option_2").innerHTML = x; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code used

```
<ul data-rules="{"Black_0":["0"],"White_1":["0"],"Natural Wood (Light)_2":["0"],"Natural Wood (Dark)_3":["0"]}" data-rulestype="{"Black_0":[""],"White_1":[""],"Natural Wood (Light)_2":[""],"Natural Wood (Dark)_3":[""]}" class="tmcp-ul-wrap tmcp-elements tm-extra-product-options-radio tm-element-ul-radio element_1 use_images_containter">
    <li class="tmcp-field-wrap tm-per-row">
        <input class="tmcp-field tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" name="tmcp_radio_1" data-price="" data-rules="["0"]" data-rulestype="[""]" data-image="http://82.10.114.15/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bournemouth-pier-black.jpg" data-imagep="" value="Black_0" id="tmcp_choice_1_0_7" tabindex="7" type="radio" checked="checked">
        <label for="tmcp_choice_1_0_7"><img class="tmlazy radio_image tm-tooltip lazy-hidden" alt="" src="http://82.10.114.15/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bournemouth-pier-black.jpg" data-tm-tooltip-swatch="on"><span class="checkbox_image_label" style="display: none;">Black</span></label>
        <span class="amount  hidden">£0.00</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add the related html, how you can select image?

Comment: As mentioned, we need the html. Without seeing what your radios have been replaced with, or how that is working, it is hard to guess where the problem is.